# Server-side Google Sign-In, way to encrypt/decrypt data with Google-managed secrets?

Tags: authentication, encryption, oauth, google-signin

It's rather straightforward to use the Google Sign-In library on the server side and attain a GoogleIdToken to validate a user's identity. However, I'd like to encrypt per-user data in my database with a secret that's unique to every user. Is there an easy way to do this? If not using Google Sign-in, you can derive keys from a user's password, but that's obviously not possible here.

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking to do one of two things: 1) Call a method such as GoogleIdToken.Encrypt(plaintex) or GootleIdToken.Decrypt(cyphertext) - clearly these don't exist, but maybe something similar does, in a related object, somewhere? 2) Being able to store and retrieve a secret on a per-user basis that's only available to my application and only for logged-on users, such as GoogleIdToken.SetUserSecret(symmkey) or GoogleIdToken.GetUserSecret(). Again, these methods don't exist but maybe something similar does?

Comment: What is the requirement? option 1) is different than 2) in 2) your app server has visibility over the secret, in which case you can derive secret keys from user id or something.

Comment: The requirement is to encrypt data in such a way that nothing is compromised if the database ends up in the wrong hands. From this perspective, 1) and 2) are not that different. I don't mind temporary visibility of the secret though. Having said that, I don't think the user ID has enough entropy for it to be an input to something like PBKDF/scrypt/etc, and it's also not exactly a secret.

Comment: Does the data need to be available to your application front-end (Javascript), backend or both? Also any reason why the encryption needs to be per-user rather than some application-wide random salt?

Comment: Data would need to be available to both backend and frontend. App-wide encryption key doesn't seem to make much sense since my application would need to store that somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you're drawing a parallel to using the user's password to derive an encryption key, but since you're talking about that as an alternative if you weren't using Google Sign-On, that implies your talking about using the password that users would authenticate with. That's a bad idea.

Users need to be able to change their authentication password, and that will be a major hassle for you if you're encrypting with it. It will require you to decrypt everything with the old password and then re-encrypt it with the new one.

So what you need to find is something that you can pull out of the GoogleIdToken that will never change. Email addresses change, so I wouldn't use that. Perhaps the user id, which you can get with GoogleIdToken.getPayload().getSubject() is what you want. Then what you would want to do is derive a key from that. I would look for ways to combine it with other information that the user gives you that really is secret, though.

Comment: The spec states "REQUIRED. Subject Identifier. A locally unique and never reassigned identifier within the Issuer for the End-User, which is intended to be consumed by the Client, e.g., 24400320 or AItOawmwtWwcT0k51BayewNvutrJUqsvl6qs7A4. It MUST NOT exceed 255 ASCII characters in length. The sub value is a case sensitive string."  1) I see no guarantee this is cryptographically hard to guess, has many bits, etc. 2) I can find nothing that guarantees it won't change.  Some sources appear to suggest the opposite, in fact.  So this doesn't look like a good option.

Comment: Combining it with a secret (and maybe also with a salt) to generate an HMAC would not be terrible, but even then I'd probably only use a key derived from that HMAC to encrypt a real randomly-generated key for encrypting the user's actual data.

Comment: The problem with the identifier is that it's not much of a secret. It's the same on all websites implementing Google Sign-In. Combining it with a local secret value means then I have to safeguard that value, which is the exact problem I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: In that case, I think you need your account creation process to give the users the opportunity to create a secret of their own that is separate from their authentication. if this is all going on server-side, though, that secret will at least theoretically be something you can learn. If that's the case, there's not a lot of advantage over you just using your own secret. If you're doing client-side encryption though, then I agree.

Answer (score 0):

The information you receive during a Google sign on is intended for authentication purposes.  The id token is encoded as a Json Web Token.  There is nothing secret in a JWT.

The information is cryptographically signed by the authentication provider, so you can verify the information.  This is of no help for deriving secrets, though.

Looks like you'll have to find another way.

Comment: For reference: https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec#.wq3o9ygj3

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with just Google Sign-In, but you can use Firebase to convert user authentication credentials (with Google or other systems) into storage restricted to access by the user.

You can do this by using Firebase Authentication; you can [authenticate your users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) from your backend, then store the encryption key for the user in [User private](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/user-security) objects. (Or possibly just store the data you wanted to secure in those objects.)

Then your server can be set up to not have the access rights to read user data unless those users are logged in, although you will still have administrative ability to read all user data.